# Can you use a or (||) operator inside a ternary operator condition statment in to determina if null or undefined

Tags: javascript

When I try and check if a value is undefined or null the undefined variable get's checked but not the null value I am doing this inside a click handler for google maps

```
map.data.addListener('click', function(event) {
var altitudeMode = event.feature.getProperty('altitudeMode') === undefined || null ?  
  "" 
: 
  "<tbody>"+"<th>altitudeMode:</th>" + "<td>" + event.feature.getProperty('altitudeMode') + "</td>" + "</tbody>";
}
```

Comment: `[undefined, null].includes(event.feature.getProperty('altitudeMode'))` but if altitudeMode is never going to be a falsly value, then just do a truthy check. `var altitudeMode = event.feature.getProperty('altitudeMode') ? "<tbody....." : ""`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is `(property === undefined) || (null)`, not testing the property for either being undefined or being null. To do that, just write

```
event.feature.getProperty('altitudeMode') == null
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a separate strict comparison for the `null` value in your ternary operation like this:

```
const altMode = event.feature.getProperty('altitudeMode');
var altitudeMode = altMode === undefined || altMode === null ?  
  "" 
: 
  "<tbody>....</tbody>";
```